# How to apply pagination on checkbox options of form elements in Drupal?

Tags: forms

How to apply pagination on checkbox options of form elements in Drupal?

for example:

```
$form['display'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Type'),
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#description' => t('Please Select Type'),
        '#options' => theme('xyz',array($disclaimer_term)).theme('pager'),
    );
```

Is this possible to limit the number of options of checkbox?

Comment: what exactly you want? didn't getting.

Comment: I am fetching all fids from file_managed table of Drupal in a form as checkbox options. So there is a huge amount of data in this table. I want to manage 200 records of fids in `checkbox options`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). It allows you to list data and perform (programmable) actions. You could use Views' pagination system.

Comment: Drupal has nothing to help with something that niche, you'll need to implement it manually. Sounds like a very awkward UX you're trying to create though, if I'm honest. Why not just do it the normal way and have a multi-select list? You can install Chosen if your users find ctrl-clicking multiple options annoying

Answer (score 0):

Best option you can do it without checkbox in pagination you can enable module like [multiselect widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_multiselect_widget) which work like dropdown with checkbox field.